# "Failed to locate template" error when building development environment

Tags: wordpress, developer

I am new trying to setup my development environment with the build kit tool. I am using [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/i) on Ubuntu 14.04 . I have problems with the `civibuild` command accessing my XAMPP MySQL via the command line to create the database so I have used the `gitify` command to set up, but when try to run `GenCode.php`, I get this error:

> civicrm_domain.version := 4.7.alpha1
>
> Parsing schema description schema/Schema.xml
>       Extracting database information
>       Extracting table information
>       PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Failed to locate template for civicrm.config.php' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/civisocialdev/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/CodeGen/Config.php:34
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/civisocialdev/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/CodeGen/Config.php(10): CRM_Core_CodeGen_Config->setupCms()
>       #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/civisocialdev/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/CodeGen/Main.php(115): CRM_Core_CodeGen_Config->run()
>       #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/civisocialdev/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/CodeGen/Main.php(100): CRM_Core_CodeGen_Main->runAllTasks()
>       #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/civisocialdev/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/civicrm/xml/GenCode.php(38): CRM_Core_CodeGen_Main->main()
>       #4 {main}
>         thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/civisocialdev/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/CodeGen/Config.php on line 34

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing your path has three `civicrm`s in it - that seems like it's not correct, normally there are two with Wordpress.

Second - if you're using Ubuntu, there's really no need for XAMPP.  You can just install your LAMP stack using `apt-get` or `synaptic`.  This is much closer to the standard setup, and you're likely to find better assistance that way!

Comment: I used gitify to setup my environment, at what level am I supposed to run the gitify command, the first or second level of the civicrm directory after installatio ie /opt/lampp/htdocs/civisocialdev/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/  or /opt/lampp/htdocs/civisocialdev/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm  ?